# Inno Setup - Correct use of [Types], [Components] and [Tasks]

Tags: inno-setup

I am writing a script that requires users to choose which parts of the application to install:

Application only, DataBase Engine only, Data only, or any combination of these.

I know I should be using the `[Components]` section to define these, but I am getting confused by the interplay between Types, Components and Tasks - for one, I thought `[Tasks]` was for "extra" installations, but then I saw code that links explicitly the three.

Can anyone point me to a good explanation of how these work together? - I am sure there is one...

Thanks

Answer (score 19, accepted):

*Components* are made of one or more *Types*. In the script you'll use the *Components* as  selector depending on the *Type* chosen by the end user. *Components* can be used in the *Tasks* because depending on the *Types* chosen by the user a *Task* will have or not to be executed.

For example:

```
; 'Types': What get displayed during the setup
[Types]
Name: "full";     Description: "Full installation";
Name: "app";      Description: "Fapplication only";
Name: "dbengine"; Description: "Database engine only";
Name: "data";     Description: "Data only";

; Components are used inside the script and can be composed of a set of 'Types'
[Components]
Name: "full";     Description: "Full installation";   Types: full app dbengine app
Name: "app";      Description: "Fapplication only";   Types: app
Name: "dbengine"; Description: "Database engine only";Types: dbengine
Name: "data";     Description: "Data only";           Types: data

; Defines which files are setup, based on the differents components
[Files]
Source: "MyApp.exe";  DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion; Components: full app
Source: "ADll.dll";   DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion; Components: full app
Source: "Engine.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion; Components: full dbengine
Source: "data_0";     DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion; Components: full data
Source: "data_1";     DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion; Components: full data

; In the same fashion, a task can be set for a specific component
[Tasks]
Name: desktopicon; Description: "Create a &desktop icon"; GroupDescription: "Additional icons:"; Components: full app
```

Comment: What if certain files are only installed when a certain task is selected? Do they still need the Components specified then?

Answer (score 2):

My understanding is that a Component is a basically a set of files - it constitutes a major 'component' of what can be installed. A 'type' of installation is a selection of components that it makes sense to install together.  Here's the way I would code @az01 's example.

```
; Lists types of installations - the user is presented
; with a list containing these Descriptions:
[Types]
Name: "full";        Description: "Full installation";
Name: "app-only";    Description: "Application only";
Name: "engine-only"; Description: "Database engine only";
Name: "data-only";   Description: "Data only";

; This lists the installable components of the product and
; specifies which type of install they are included in
[Components]
Name: "app";      Description: "Application";     Types: full app-only
Name: "engine";   Description: "Database engine"; Types: full engine-only
Name: "data";     Description: "Data";            Types: full data-only

; each file is assigned to one component, unless it is shared between
; components, in which case maybe it should go in a 'shared' component.
[Files]
Source: "MyApp.exe";  DestDir: "{app}"; Flags:; Components: app
Source: "ADll.dll";   DestDir: "{app}"; Flags:; Components: app
Source: "Engine.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags:; Components: engine
Source: "data_0";     DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion; Components: data
Source: "data_1";     DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion; Components: data
```

Answer (score 1):

A complete explanation can be found on Innosetup help page :
[Components and Tasks Parameters](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=componentstasksparams)

and [[Components] section](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=componentssection)

I give you below a generic sample :

```
[Components]

Name: a; Description: a
Name: b; Description: b

[Tasks]
Name: p; Description: a or b; Components: a or b
Name: q; Description: a and b; Components: a and b
Name: r; Description: not a or b; Components: not a or b
Name: s; Description: not (a or b); Components: not (a or b)
Name: t; Description: a or b - old style; Components: a b
```