# Skipping custom pages based on optional components in Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup

In a prior question I asked how to have three optional components, where the user could also specify the locations for each component separately (e.g. a code part and two HTML web applications). @Miral gave me a great answer which I have now implemented:
[three components in three user defined locations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13728134/three-components-in-three-user-defined-locations)

I have a small esthetic issue remaining. I am always creating and asking the user for a `CreateInputDirPage`, in the wizard. The question comes after the `wpSelectComponents`.

Question: How do I skip the page if the component was not selected. That is, how do I skip my custom page?

I have a feeling it has to do with `ShouldSkipPage()`. But I have no idea what the `PageID` for my custom page is, and how to test to see what components were selected.

> function ShouldSkipPage(PageID: Integer): Boolean;
>
> The wizard calls this event function to determine whether or not a particular page (specified by PageID) should be shown at all. If you return True, the page will be skipped; if you return False, the page may be shown.

My script is enclosed below:

```pascal
[Components]
Name: "Watson"; Description: "Watson Component"; Types: onlywatson full
Name: "Toby"; Description: "Toby Component"; Types: onlytoby full
Name: "Sherlock"; Description: "Sherlock Component"; Types: onlysherlock full

[Code]
var 
    TobyDirPage: TInputDirWizardPage;
    SherlockDirPage: TInputDirWizardPage;

procedure InitializeWizard;
begin
  TobyDirPage := CreateInputDirPage(wpSelectComponents,
    'Select Location for Toby Web Pages', 'Where should we store the sample Toby application files?',
    'The sample Toby stand-alone map application will be saved in the following folder.'#13#10#13#10 +
    'To continue, click Next. If you would like to select a different folder, click Browse.',
    False, 'New Folder');
  { Add item (with an empty caption) }
  TobyDirPage.Add('');
  { Set initial value (optional) }
  TobyDirPage.Values[0] := ExpandConstant('c:\wwwroot\Toby');
  
  SherlockDirPage := CreateInputDirPage(wpSelectComponents,
    'Select Location for Sherlock Web Pages', 'Where should we store the Sherlock Catalog Search Tool?',
    'Sherlock.html and it'#39 + 's associated files will be saved in the following folder.'#13#10#13#10 +
    'To continue, click Next. If you would like to select a different folder, click Browse.',
    False, 'New Folder');
  { Add item (with an empty caption) }
  SherlockDirPage.Add('');
  { Set initial value (optional) }
  SherlockDirPage.Values[0] := ExpandConstant('c:\wwwroot\Sherlock');
end;

function GetTobyDir(Param: String): String;
begin
  { Return the selected TobyDir }
  Result := TobyDirPage.Values[0];
end;

function GetSherlockDir(Param: String): String;
begin
  { Return the selected TobyDir }
  Result := SherlockDirPage.Values[0];
end;
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

As you correctly forefelt, you need to use the [`ShouldSkipPage`](http://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_scriptevents.htm#ShouldSkipPage) event handler to conditionally skip the page. To check if a certain component is selected use the [`IsComponentSelected`](http://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_isxfunc_iscomponentselected.htm) function and finally, to get ID of your custom page you need to store its [`ID`](http://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_scriptclasses.htm#TWizardPage). Putting all together might give you the following example script:

```pascal
[Setup]
AppName=My Program
AppVersion=1.5
DefaultDirName={pf}\My Program
OutputDir=userdocs:Inno Setup Examples Output

[Components]
Name: "help"; Description: "Help File";

[Code]
var
  CustomPageID: Integer;

procedure InitializeWizard;
var
  CustomPage: TInputDirWizardPage;
begin
  CustomPage := CreateInputDirPage(wpSelectComponents, 'Caption', 
    'Description', 'SubCaption', False, 'NewFolderName');
  CustomPage.Add('Input');
  { store your custom page ID to further use in the ShouldSkipPage event }
  CustomPageID := CustomPage.ID;
end;

function ShouldSkipPage(PageID: Integer): Boolean;
begin
  { initialize result to not skip any page (not necessary, but safer) }
  Result := False;
  { if the page that is asked to be skipped is your custom page, then... }
  if PageID = CustomPageID then
    { if the component is not selected, skip the page }
    Result := not IsComponentSelected('help');
end;
```

Comment: I think it is THE answer, but I have been busy today, and I want to test it out. But to me, it looks thorough and well explained. Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome! If you'd need any help related to this question, don't hesitate to drop a comment here ;-)

Comment: thanks for the answer. If I choose to not check that component, the page is really not shown as expected,  but if I first choose the component, see the custom page and then go back to the components selection and change my choice - uncheck that component, the custom page is appears... is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: @one, that should not happen. Could you share a minimalistic script in which this would be reproducable ?

Comment: @TLama: He keeps Wizard page objects already so there's no need in caching their ID's as well. The check in ShouldSkipPage will look like `if (PageID = TobyDirPage.ID) then ... else if (PageID = SherlockDirPage.ID) then ...`

Comment: In InnoSetup 6, the function is [`WizardIsComponentSelected`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_isxfunc_wizardiscomponentselected.htm).

Answer (score 7):

My take on this is to use the TWizardPageShouldSkipEvent, I've made only a case-and-point script:

```pascal
[Code]
var 
    TobyDirPage: TInputDirWizardPage;

function SkipEvent (Sender: TWizardPage): Boolean;
begin
    Result := not IsComponentSelected('Toby');
end; 

procedure InitializeWizard;
begin
    TobyDirPage := CreateInputDirPage(wpSelectComponents, yadda yadda yadda
    TobyDirPage.OnShouldSkipPage := @SkipEvent;
end;
```

Now, `OnShouldSkipPage` fires right after pressing Next on `wpSelectComponents` and before `TobyDirPage` gets painted and since you can attach that event to the page itself you don't need to fiddle with PageID's.