# Change WizardSmallImageFile programmatically - Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup

Is it possible to change the top image on a wizard form depending on the wizard form. I can change the left side image but would like to change the top (small image).

```pascal
procedure CurPageChanged(CurPageID: Integer);
begin
  if CurPageID = 4 then
   filename:= 'babylontoolbar.bmp'
  else
   filename:= 'label2-crop.bmp';
  ExtractTemporaryFile(filename); 
  (*WizardForm.WizardSmallImageFile.Bitmap.LoadFromFile(ExpandConstant('{tmp}\'+FileName));*)

  WizardForm.WizardBitmapImage.Bitmap.LoadFromFile(ExpandConstant('{tmp}\' + FileName));
end;
```

I just would like to know how to reference the small file to replace the `WizardSmallImageFile` which does not work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`WizardSmallImageFile`](http://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_setup_wizardsmallimagefile.htm) directive is mapped to the [`WizardSmallBitmapImage`](http://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_scriptclasses.htm#TWizardForm) control of the `WizardForm`, so in code you can access it this way (anyway, do not hardcode page ID numbers, but instead use the intended [`PageID`](http://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_scriptevents.htm#PageID) constants):

```pascal
procedure CurPageChanged(CurPageID: Integer);
var
  FileName: string;
begin
  if CurPageID = wpInfoBefore then
    FileName := 'babylontoolbar.bmp'
  else
    FileName := 'label2-crop.bmp';

  ExtractTemporaryFile(FileName);
  WizardForm.WizardSmallBitmapImage.Bitmap.LoadFromFile(ExpandConstant('{tmp}\' + FileName));
end;
```

Comment: Thanks.  One question though everytime I try to reference a custom page in CurPageChanged(CurPageID: Integer); I get a type mismatch. as in curPageId = Opt then  Is there a way to ouput a variable such as Page name to a msgBox.  That way I could figure it out myself.

Comment: You're welcome! And sorry, I've been answering something else right now. Those `wp..` constants are integers, so you shouldn't get type mismatch errors. Their names are quite self-explanable, but if you won't be sure, you might call [`this procedure`](http://pastebin.com/TDxQK8VX), which shows you that.

Comment: That works great but for the custom page it of course shows unknown or custom page id.  The page was defined using   Opt := CreateInputQueryPage(wpInfoBefore,'Delta Toolbar','','');   I have been assuming that the page name would be Opt but obviously I am missing something.  The error I get is type mismatch.

Comment: The id of that custom page would be `Opt.Id`.

Answer (score 0):

Once again TLama has the answers, just have to keep googling.  For those trying to do something similar to this and having problems finding the answer check out [Skipping custom pages based on optional components in Inno Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13921535/skipping-custom-pages-based-on-optional-components-in-inno-setup)

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding; yes, for sure, if you're creating a custom page you should, as you correctly pointed, store at least `ID` of the page you create. You can then determine at least through the `YourPage.ID` your real page `ID` instead of hardcoded number `4`.

Comment: No problem.  Two weeks ago I new nothing about Inno Setup or the scripting language and with the help of stack overflow and mostly your excellent examples both to me and other inno setup users I feel like I have grasped at least the major fundamentals of the language.  As you get older I find that understanding the technical type help pages a struggle but you have made it much easier.  Thanks so much.