# Inno Setup: Asking for directory page if a task checked

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

Under the task section I have

```
[Tasks]
Name: "desktopicon"; Description: "{cm:CreateDesktopIcon}"; \
    GroupDescription: "{cm:AdditionalIcons}"; Flags: unchecked
Name: "installFolder"; Description: "Install project folder."; \
    GroupDescription:" folder";
```

and in the `Files` section is this particular folder

```
Source: "C:\\Output\LEA\*.*"; DestDir: {code:GetDataDir}; \
    Flags: createallsubdirs recursesubdirs ignoreversion;
```

My aim is to test the for the checked button and then have a window to ask for the directory to install the folder to.

```pascal
if WizardForm.TasksList.Checked[3] then
  GetDataDir;
```

Can this be done without the need to create pages or the one page to get the directory?
Also, is this a good way to handle extra files that are optional and will be installed to a different location than the default `{app}` location?

The confusing part for me thus far is when it's all compiled, the `GetDataDir` is being called before the page to select Tasks. So I choose my directory and then I'm asked whether I want to install it or not. I don't know how to go about getting the `GetDataDir` to occur afterwards.

Comment: OT: You can use [`IsTaskSelected`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_istaskselected) function to check if a certain task is selected or not. About the rest; I'm a bit lost what is your aim. Yes, you can specify whatever directory you want in your `GetDataDir` getter function; there's no requirement for creating a custom page for specifying directories. And yes, that's the way to change target dirctory at runtime.

Comment: Made an update. Essentially, my GetdataDir is being called before, rather than after I make my additional task choice.

Comment: Your `GetDataDir` getter might be called multiple times, but it should not IMHO be called before the task selection page. But, you don't even need to do anything with it. All you need is to evaluate that value just before those files are going to be installed. And that's what Inno Setup does for you. In all cases, do not call that `GetDataDir` getter manually (because you don't need to) and never do any actions like creating windows, pages or similar there. Just return the value you want to pass to the script entry parameter from it. That's the only purpose of `{code:}` getter functions.

Comment: [Related question based on `[Components]`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13921535/588306).

Answer (score 2):

The wizard model in Inno Setup means you should always create the wizard pages, but you can skip the ones that don't need to be shown.

This can be done in the `ShouldSkipPage()` event function by calling `IsTaskSelected()`:

```pascal
function ShouldSkipPage(PageID: Integer): Boolean;
begin
  if (PageID = InstallFolderPage.ID) and not IsTaskSelected('installFolder') then
    Result := True
  else
    Result := False
end;
```

In this case, with only a single check, it can be shortened to:

```pascal
function ShouldSkipPage(PageID: Integer): Boolean;
begin
  Result := (PageID = InstallFolderPage.ID) and not IsTaskSelected('installFolder')
end;
```

As [TLama](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20051709/innosetup-asking-for-directory-page-if-a-task-checked#comment29867880_20051709) said, you don't need to do anything special in the `{code:...}` functions, just return the appropriate value directly.

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to add '; Tasks: installFolder' at the end of your Source... line, then it won't be called unless the task as been selected.

```
Source: "C:\\Output\LEA\*.*"; DestDir: {code:GetDataDir}; Flags: createallsubdirs recursesubdirs ignoreversion; Tasks: installFolder
```