# Inno Setup conditionally skip the Finished page

Tags: inno-setup

I am trying to conditionally skip the Finished page through use of a `Task` to allow the user the choice of whether they want to have Setup 'Auto-Finish'. I have tried the following:

```pascal
[Setup]
DisableFinishedPage={code:GetAutoFinishStatus}

[Tasks]
Name: "AutoFinish"; Description: "Auto-Finish Installation"; \
    GroupDescription: "Post Installation Options"; Flags: unchecked; Components: MyApp

[Code]
function GetAutoFinishStatus(Param: String): String;
begin
  if IsTaskSelected('AutoFinish') then
    Result := 'yes';
end;
```

But, when compiling, I get:

> Value of [Setup] section directive "DisableFinishedPage" is invalid.

I therefore assume that this directive does not accept a conditional value through code, even though other `[Setup]` directives do? Is there another way to achieve this, or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`DisableFinishedPage` directive](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_disablefinishedpage) does not support scripted constants.

Use the [`ShouldSkipPage` event function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents&anchor=ShouldSkipPage) instead:

```pascal
function ShouldSkipPage(PageID: Integer): Boolean;
begin
  Result := False;

  if PageID = wpFinished then
  begin
    Result := IsTaskSelected('AutoFinish');
  end;
end;
```

---

See also [Skipping custom pages based on optional components in Inno Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13921535/850848).