# Optional components and types in inno-setup script

Tags: inno-setup

I have created the following InnoSetup script for adding in optional components following advice from this StackOverflow answer: [Inno Setup - Correct use of [Types], [Components] and [Tasks]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8890828/inno-setup-correct-use-of-types-components-and-tasks) .

The problem is when I run the script and choose to install or Sherlock or Toby types I see that Watson is also installed.

```
; Script generated by the Inno Setup Script Wizard.
; SEE THE DOCUMENTATION FOR DETAILS ON CREATING INNO SETUP SCRIPT FILES!

#define MyAppName "Watson"
#define MyAppVersion "1.0"
#define MyAppExeName "Watson.exe"

[Setup]
; NOTE: The value of AppId uniquely identifies this application.
; Do not use the same AppId value in installers for other applications.
; (To generate a new GUID, click Tools | Generate GUID inside the IDE.)
AppId={{15C6F30B-A29D-48AD-A97A-9FDB4DD80EAE}
AppName={#MyAppName}
AppVersion={#MyAppVersion}
;AppVerName={#MyAppName} {#MyAppVersion}
AppPublisher={#MyAppPublisher}
AppPublisherURL={#MyAppURL}
AppSupportURL={#MyAppURL}
AppUpdatesURL={#MyAppURL}
DefaultDirName={pf}\{#MyAppName}
DefaultGroupName={#MyAppName}
OutputDir=Z:\EGPL Librarian Releases\Setup Scripts\All Install
OutputBaseFilename=LibrarianSetup
Compression=lzma
SolidCompression=yes
WizardImageFile=compiler:WizModernImage-IS.bmp
WizardSmallImageFile=compiler:WizModernSmallImage-IS.bmp
VersionInfoVersion=1.0
VersionInfoCompany=Draper Laboratory
VersionInfoDescription=Watson Librarian Server
VersionInfoTextVersion=Watson 1.0
VersionInfoCopyright=2012
VersionInfoProductName=EGPL Librarian
VersionInfoProductVersion=1.0
VersionInfoProductTextVersion=Watson 1.0

[Languages]
Name: "english"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Default.isl"

[Tasks]
Name: "desktopicon"; Description: "{cm:CreateDesktopIcon}"; GroupDescription: "{cm:AdditionalIcons}"; Flags: unchecked; Components: Watson Full

[Files]
Source: "Z:\EGPL Librarian Releases\Sample Installation\Watson\Watson.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion; Components: Watson Full
Source: "Z:\EGPL Librarian Releases\Sample Installation\Watson\Devart.Data.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion; Components: Watson Full
Source: "Z:\EGPL Librarian Releases\Sample Installation\Watson\Devart.Data.Linq.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion; Components: Watson Full
Source: "Z:\EGPL Librarian Releases\Sample Installation\Watson\Devart.Data.PostgreSql.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion; Components: Watson Full
Source: "Z:\EGPL Librarian Releases\Sample Installation\Watson\Devart.Data.PostgreSql.Linq.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion; Components: Watson Full
Source: "Z:\EGPL Librarian Releases\Sample Installation\Watson\Devart.Data.PostgreSql.xml"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion; Components: Watson Full
Source: "Z:\EGPL Librarian Releases\Sample Installation\Watson\Devart.Data.xml"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion; Components: Watson Full
Source: "Z:\EGPL Librarian Releases\Sample Installation\Watson\Ionic.Zip.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion; Components: Watson Full
Source: "Z:\EGPL Librarian Releases\Sample Installation\Watson\Watson.application"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion; Components: Watson Full
Source: "Z:\EGPL Librarian Releases\Sample Installation\Watson\Watson.exe.config"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion; Components: Watson Full
Source: "Z:\EGPL Librarian Releases\Sample Installation\Watson\Watson.exe.manifest"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion; Components: Watson Full
Source: "Z:\EGPL Librarian Releases\Sample Installation\Watson\Watson.pdb"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion; Components: Watson Full
; Toby
Source: "Z:\EGPL Librarian Releases\Sample Installation\wwwroot\Toby\*"; DestDir: "c:\\wwwroot\Toby"; Flags: ignoreversion createallsubdirs recursesubdirs; Components: Toby Full
; Sherlock
Source: "Z:\EGPL Librarian Releases\Sample Installation\wwwroot\Sherlock\*"; DestDir: "c:\\wwwroot\Sherlock"; Flags: ignoreversion createallsubdirs recursesubdirs; Components: Sherlock Full
; NOTE: Don't use "Flags: ignoreversion" on any shared system files

[Icons]
Name: "{group}\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; Components: Full Watson
Name: "{group}\{cm:UninstallProgram,{#MyAppName}}"; Filename: "{uninstallexe}"; Components: Full Watson
Name: "{commondesktop}\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; Components: Full Watson; Tasks: desktopicon

[Run]
Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; Flags: nowait postinstall skipifsilent; Description: "{cm:LaunchProgram,{#StringChange(MyAppName, '&', '&&')}}"; Components: Watson Full

[Types]
Name: "Everything"; Description: "Install Watson, Sherlock, and Toby"
Name: "Watson"; Description: "Install Only Watson"
Name: "Toby"; Description: "Install Only Toby"
Name: "Sherlock"; Description: "Install Only Sherlock"

[Components]
Name: "Full"; Description: "Full Install"; Types: Watson Everything Toby Sherlock
Name: "Watson"; Description: "Watson Component"; Types: Watson
Name: "Toby"; Description: "Toby Component"; Types: Toby
Name: "Sherlock"; Description: "Sherlock Component"; Types: Sherlock

[Code]
function IsDotNetDetected(version: string; service: cardinal): boolean;
// Indicates whether the specified version and service pack of the .NET Framework is installed.
//
// version -- Specify one of these strings for the required .NET Framework version:
//    'v1.1.4322'     .NET Framework 1.1
//    'v2.0.50727'    .NET Framework 2.0
//    'v3.0'          .NET Framework 3.0
//    'v3.5'          .NET Framework 3.5
//    'v4\Client'     .NET Framework 4.0 Client Profile
//    'v4\Full'       .NET Framework 4.0 Full Installation
//    'v4.5'          .NET Framework 4.5
//
// service -- Specify any non-negative integer for the required service pack level:
//    0               No service packs required
//    1, 2, etc.      Service pack 1, 2, etc. required
var
    key: string;
    install, release, serviceCount: cardinal;
    check45, success: boolean;
begin
    // .NET 4.5 installs as update to .NET 4.0 Full
    if version = 'v4.5' then begin
        version := 'v4\Full';
        check45 := true;
    end else
        check45 := false;

    // installation key group for all .NET versions
    key := 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\' + version;

    // .NET 3.0 uses value InstallSuccess in subkey Setup
    if Pos('v3.0', version) = 1 then begin
        success := RegQueryDWordValue(HKLM, key + '\Setup', 'InstallSuccess', install);
    end else begin
        success := RegQueryDWordValue(HKLM, key, 'Install', install);
    end;

    // .NET 4.0/4.5 uses value Servicing instead of SP
    if Pos('v4', version) = 1 then begin
        success := success and RegQueryDWordValue(HKLM, key, 'Servicing', serviceCount);
    end else begin
        success := success and RegQueryDWordValue(HKLM, key, 'SP', serviceCount);
    end;

    // .NET 4.5 uses additional value Release
    if check45 then begin
        success := success and RegQueryDWordValue(HKLM, key, 'Release', release);
        success := success and (release >= 378389);
    end;

    result := success and (install = 1) and (serviceCount >= service);
end;


function InitializeSetup(): Boolean;
begin
    if not IsDotNetDetected('v4\Full', 0) then begin
        MsgBox('Watson requires Microsoft .NET Framework 4.0 Full Profile.'#13#13
            'Please run dotNetFx40_Full_x86_x64.exe from the install disk,' #13
            'or download from www.microsoft.com/net,'#13
            'and then re-run the WatsonSetup.exe program.', mbInformation, MB_OK);
        result := false;
    end else begin
//        MsgBox('Found Microsoft .NET Framework 4.0.', mbInformation, MB_OK);
        result := true;
    end;
end;
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Link each file with just one component, and then link each component with the different types of installation where the component (with all it's files) will be included.

for example, defining this four install types:

```
[Types]
Name: "full"; Description: "Install Watson, Sherlock, and Toby"
Name: "onlywatson"; Description: "Install Only Watson"
Name: "onlytoby"; Description: "Install Only Toby"
Name: "onlysherlock"; Description: "Install Only Sherlock"
```

You can define just three components:

```
[Components]
Name: "watson"; Description: "Watson Component"; Types: onlywatson full
Name: "toby"; Description: "Toby Component"; Types: onlytoby full
Name: "sherlock"; Description: "Sherlock Component"; Types: onlysherlock full
```

As you can see, each `component` is included in two types, one is the *only X* type of installation and the other is the *full* installation type.

Then, define your files for one component each (unless you have good reasons to include a file with no components or in different ones, but that doesn't make much sense to me).

```
[Files]
;watson
Source: "files\Watson.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion; Components: watson
Source: "files\Watson.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion; Components: watson
Source: "files\other.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion; Components: watson
; Toby
Source: "files\toby\*"; DestDir: "{app}\extras\Toby"; Flags: ignoreversion createallsubdirs recursesubdirs; Components: toby
; Sherlock
Source: "files\Sherlock\*"; DestDir: "{app}\extras\Sherlock"; Flags: ignoreversion createallsubdirs recursesubdirs; Components: sherlock
```

The same reasoning applies to other sections, like `[Icons]`, `[Tasks]` or `[Run]`, where each entry usually belongs to just one component.

I did a quick test for you, putting all this together:

```
#define MyAppName "Watson"
#define MyAppVersion "1.0"
#define MyAppExeName "watson.txt"
#define MyAppPublisher "Me.com"
#define MyAppURL "Me.com"

[Setup]
AppId={{15C6F30B-A29D-48AD-A97A-9FDB4DD80EAE}
AppName={#MyAppName}
AppVersion={#MyAppVersion}
AppPublisher={#MyAppPublisher}
AppPublisherURL={#MyAppURL}
AppSupportURL={#MyAppURL}
AppUpdatesURL={#MyAppURL}
DefaultDirName={pf}\{#MyAppName}
DefaultGroupName={#MyAppName}
OutputDir=Installer
OutputBaseFilename=LibrarianSetup
Compression=lzma
SolidCompression=yes
WizardImageFile=compiler:WizModernImage-IS.bmp
WizardSmallImageFile=compiler:WizModernSmallImage-IS.bmp
VersionInfoVersion=1.0
VersionInfoCompany=Draper Laboratory
VersionInfoDescription=Watson Librarian Server
VersionInfoTextVersion=Watson 1.0
VersionInfoCopyright=2012
VersionInfoProductName=EGPL Librarian
VersionInfoProductVersion=1.0
VersionInfoProductTextVersion=Watson 1.0

[Languages]
Name: "english"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Default.isl"

[Types]
Name: "full"; Description: "Install Watson, Sherlock, and Toby"
Name: "onlywatson"; Description: "Install Only Watson"
Name: "onlytoby"; Description: "Install Only Toby"
Name: "onlysherlock"; Description: "Install Only Sherlock"

[Components]
Name: "watson"; Description: "Watson Component"; Types: onlywatson full
Name: "toby"; Description: "Toby Component"; Types: onlytoby full
Name: "sherlock"; Description: "Sherlock Component"; Types: onlysherlock full

[Files]
;watson
Source: "files\Watson.txt"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion; Components: watson
Source: "files\Watson1.txt"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion; Components: watson
Source: "files\Watson2.txt"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion; Components: watson
; Toby
Source: "files\toby\*"; DestDir: "{app}\extras\Toby"; Flags: ignoreversion createallsubdirs recursesubdirs; Components: toby
; Sherlock
Source: "files\Sherlock\*"; DestDir: "{app}\extras\Sherlock"; Flags: ignoreversion createallsubdirs recursesubdirs; Components: sherlock
; NOTE: Don't use "Flags: ignoreversion" on any shared system files

[Icons]
Name: "{group}\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; Components: Watson
Name: "{group}\{cm:UninstallProgram,{#MyAppName}}"; Filename: "{uninstallexe}"; Components: Watson
Name: "{commondesktop}\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; Components: Watson; Tasks: desktopicon

[Run]
Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; Flags: nowait postinstall skipifsilent; Description: "{cm:LaunchProgram,{#StringChange(MyAppName, '&', '&&')}}"; Components: Watson

[Tasks]
Name: "desktopicon"; Description: "{cm:CreateDesktopIcon}"; GroupDescription: "{cm:AdditionalIcons}"; Flags: unchecked; Components: Watson
```

It is tested with Inno 5.5.2 on my machine and works as you want.

Comment: I was completely misled about this from the stack overflow article I referenced above: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8890828/inno-setup-correct-use-of-types-components-and-tasks  it is nice to have a helpful community here, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

I now have it working. The only addition I made was that the uninstall icon in Program Files should belong to all components. So that if you do a partial install, you still have the option to uninstall that partial install.

```
Name: "{group}\{cm:UninstallProgram,{#MyAppName}}"; Filename: "{uninstallexe}"; Components: Watson Sherlock Toby
```