# Select Multiple Language in Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup

I started on Inno Setup and I am already pretty advanced. I managed to understand how to install  files based on the language selected by the user. But now I wish I could let the user choose multiple languages ​​(so that all the files which belong to the language are installed) while keeping the choice of the language of the installer.

My program has a lot of documents and licenses on the basis of the language .

To be more specific , I want:

- Start the installation
- Choose the language of the installer
- ...
- Choose to install multiple language pack program.

I think I should use " check" or something like that and maybe radio buttons.

I searched the web but I have only found examples where only one language is to be installed.

Can you help me?

Thank you in advance

Comment: did you come any further with my answer ? or do you need further advice ? please let me know how far you are in your progress, maybe i can help you and improve my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not quite sure what exactly you want to do from your description but you should be able to create a custom page (http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptpages) with some checkboxes on it and install only the language files that are checked on it by using a function which returns a Boolean value for each checked language.
In the end you should have something like this.

```
[Files]
Source: "C:\filePath\German.license"; ... Check: CheckGerman
Source: "C:\filePath\French.license"; ... Check: CheckFrench

...

function InitializeSetup(): Boolean;
var 
  resultCode  : Boolean;
begin
   //Do something to check if German should be installed and set value to resultCode
   Result:=resultCode;
end;
```

Comment: Hello I found solution on another topic and forum. I use Types and Component to do what i want.

Comment: @Algorys do you have a link to the other topic/forum?

Comment: @user3161924 unfortunately, I don't know the precise address, but there are plenty of examples on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13813666/4303902 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/8891563/4303902.